# Fullcalendar using resources as a function with select menu

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

Using Fullcalendar 4, I am trying to show/hide my resources using a select menu.  When the user selects one of the providers from a menu, I want to only show that one resourc's events.

Above my fullcalendar I have my select menu:

```
<select id="toggle_providers_calendar" class="form-control" >
       <option value="1" selected>Screech Powers</option>
       <option value="2">Slater</option>
 </select>
```

I am gathering the resources I need using an ajax call on my included fullcalendar.php page.  I am storing them in an object and then trying to control which resources are shown onscreen:

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {


    var resourceData = [];

    $.getJSON('ajax_get_json.php?what=schedule_providers_at_location',
        function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index) {
                resourceData.push({
                    id: data[index].value,
                    title: data[index].text
                });
            });
        console.log(resourceData);
        });

    //below, set the visible resources to whatever is selected in the menu
    //using 1 in order for that to show at start
    var visibleResourceIds = ["1"];

    //below, get the selected id when the the menu is changed and use that in the toggle resource function
    $('#toggle_providers_calendar').change(function() {
        toggleResource($('#toggle_providers_calendar').val());
    });

    var calendar_full = document.getElementById('calendar_full');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendar_full, {
        events: {
            url: 'ajax_get_json.php?what=location_appointments'
        },
        height: 700,
        resources: function(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {

                // below, I am trying to filter resources by whether their id is in visibleResourceIds.
                var filteredResources = [];

                filteredResources = resourceData.filter(function(x) {
                  return visibleResourceIds.indexOf(x.id) !== -1;
                });

                successCallback(filteredResources);

        },
       ...
       });

       // below, my toggle_providers_calendar will trigger this function. Feed it resourceId.
      function toggleResource(resourceId) {
        var index = visibleResourceIds.indexOf(resourceId);
        if (index !== -1) {
          visibleResourceIds.splice(index, 1);
        } else {
          visibleResourceIds.push(resourceId);
        }

        calendar.refetchResources();
      }
```

To make sure the getJSON is working, I have console.log(resourceData).  The information in the console once it's gathered is:

```
[{id: '1', title: 'Screech Powers'}, {id: '2', title: 'Slater}]
```

... the above are the correct resources that can be chosen/rendered.  So that seems to be okay.

On page load, no resources show at all, when resource id of '1' (Screech Powers) should be shown per my code.  Well, at least, that's what I am trying to do right now.

When the menu changes, resources will show/hide, but not based on what's selected; the logic of only showing what is selected in the menu doesn't seem to be working.

I used to use a URL request for my resources: 'ajax_get_json.php?what=schedule_providers_at_location', and it worked fine!  All resources show then their events properly. I am just trying to modify it by using a menu to show/hide the resources as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'm doing to make it happen so far! In case someone comes across this post ever, this will help.

Here's my code before my fullcalendar code.

```
    var resourceData = [];
    var visibleResourceIds = [];

    $.getJSON('ajax_get_json.php?what=schedule_providers_at_location',
        function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index) {
                resourceData.push({
                    id: data[index].value,
                    title: data[index].text
                });

            });
        });


    $('#toggle_providers_calendar').change(function() {
        toggleResource($('#toggle_providers_calendar').val());
    });
```

My select menu with id 'toggle_providers_calendar' is the same as my original post.  My fullcalendar resources as a function is the same too.

After the calendar is rendered, here are the changes I made to my toggle resources function:

```
    // menu button/dropdown will trigger this function. Feed it resourceId.
    function toggleResource(resourceId) {
        visibleResourceIds = [];

        //if select all...  see if undefined from loading on initial load = true
        if ((resourceId == '') || (resourceId === undefined)) {

            $.map( resourceData, function( value, index ) {
                 visibleResourceIds.push(value.id);
            });

        }

      var index = visibleResourceIds.indexOf(resourceId);
      if (index !== -1) {
        visibleResourceIds.splice(index, 1);
      } else {
        visibleResourceIds.push(resourceId);
      }

      calendar.refetchResources();

    }
```

This causes the resources to show and hide properly.  If the user selects "Show All" that works too!

In order to have a default resource show on load, I add this to my fullcalendar script:

```
        loading: function(bool) {

        if (bool) {
            //insert code if still loading
            $('.loader').show();
        } else {
            $('.loader').hide();

            if (initial_load) {
                initial_load = false;
                //code here once done loading and initial_load = true                 
                var default_resource_to_show = "<?php echo $default_provider; ?>";
                if (default_resource_to_show) {
                    //set the menu to that provider and trigger the change event to toggleresrource()
                    $('#toggle_providers_calendar').val(default_provider).change();
                } else {
                    //pass in nothing meaning 'select all' providers for scheduler to see
                    toggleResource();
                }
            }
        }

    },
```

I am using a bool variable of initial_load to see if the page was just loaded (basically not loading data without a page refresh).  The bool of initial_load = true is set outside of DOMContentLoaded

```
<script>
//show selected date in title box
var initial_load = true;
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
```

My only current problem is that when toggleResource function is called, the all day vertical time block boundaries don't line up with the rest of the scheduler.  Once I start navigating, they do, but I don't understand why it looks like this on initial load or when toggleResource() is called:

[image]

Any thoughts on how to correct the alignment of the allday vertical blocks?

Comment: Based on a suggestion from a member, I started a new thread/question based on this problem.