# fullcalendar when render resources, all-day lines don't lined up

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

Previous post which lead to this issue: [Fullcalendar using resources as a function with select menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56742274/fullcalendar-using-resources-as-a-function-with-select-menu)

Based on my previous post, I have an issue using fullcalendar 4.  When I am using resources as a function, my all-day blocks do not line up with my scheduler time slots.  You can see it in the picture.

Here's my resources function:

```
        resources: function(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
            // Filter resources by whether their id is in visibleResourceIds.
            var filteredResources = [];

            filteredResources = resourceData.filter(function(x) {
              return visibleResourceIds.indexOf(x.id) !== -1;
            });

            successCallback(filteredResources);

    },
```

Here's my toggleresource function:

```
    // menu button/dropdown will trigger this function. Feed it resourceId.
    function toggleResource(resourceId) {
        visibleResourceIds = [];

        //if select all...  see if undefined from loading on initial load = true
        if ((resourceId == '') || (resourceId === undefined)) {

            $.map( resourceData, function( value, index ) {
                 visibleResourceIds.push(value.id);
            });

        }

      var index = visibleResourceIds.indexOf(resourceId);
      if (index !== -1) {
        visibleResourceIds.splice(index, 1);
      } else {
        visibleResourceIds.push(resourceId);
      }

      calendar.refetchResources();
```

Other related code (when the menu changes, the resources of the selected menu item show only in fullcalendar):

```
var resourceData = [];
var visibleResourceIds = [];

$.getJSON('ajax_get_json.php?what=schedule_providers_at_location',
    function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index) {
            resourceData.push({
                id: data[index].value,
                title: data[index].text
            });

        });
    });


$('#toggle_providers_calendar').change(function() {
    toggleResource($('#toggle_providers_calendar').val());
});
```

The resources show/hide just fine based on the selected menu resource, but look at the allday blocks - they don't line up after the resources are refetched for some reason.  They correct themselves as the user navigates the scheduler though!

[image]

---

UPDATE BELOW

---

After looking around it looks like when refetchevents is called, the class .fc-week loses the following css:

```
   style="border-right-width: 1px; margin-right: 20px;"
```

Here's a full pic of the calendar on initial load:

[image]

After I click a one of the navigation arrow, the all-day lines meet up with the rest of the calendar times because that style is applied to .fc-week.

[image]

I don't have any special css applied to the calendar and I am not using any themes that would get rid of this: at least not that I see now.

Here's the html that houses the calendar:

```
<div class="portlet-body">
    <div class='loader'></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="calendar_full" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 15px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In order to fix this, I can add this following line after the resources are refetched in my toggleResources function:

```
$('#calendar_full .fc-week').css('border-right-width', '1px').css('margin-right', '20px');
```

I am going to keep looking as to why this css disappears after the resources are refetched.  I wonder if it could be a glitch?

Comment: Do you have some custom CSS there in your page, and/or at a fullCalendar theme in use? First thing to try is going back to the default fullCalendar theme, and removing any other CSS from your page, and see if you still have the same issue.

Comment: Thanks, ADyson. I updated my question with some more images after looking around as you suggested.  Not sure if the new images make anything stand out.

Comment: That wasn't what I asked.